# Ansible playbook change user with shell commands

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I am new to Ansible and willing to write a small playbook that switches to another user, gets into Postgres data base, do some changes, exit the data base and switch back to the original user.

This is what I would do manually, but I want to put these commands in the playbook:

```
sudo su - postgres
psql postgres
DROP DATABASE scm;
CREATE DATABASE scm OWNER scm ENCODING 'UTF8';
\q   ##This will quit the database
exit ##This will quit postgres user back to original user
```

I started writing it into a playbook but it seems to not work:

```
---

- name: TEST
  hosts: master_servers
  tasks: 
  - name: Delete DB
    shell:
      cmd: psql postgres | DROP DATABASE scm; | CREATE DATABASE scm OWNER scm ENCODING 'UTF8'; | \q | exit
    become: yes
    become_user: postgres
```

Here is the error I get:

```
fatal: [xx.xx.xx.xx]: FAILED! => {
"msg": "Failed to change ownership of the temporary files Ansible needs to create despite connecting as a privileged user. Unprivileged become user would be unable to read the file."
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `name: TEST` playbook has a deep misunderstanding about how shell pipes work

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you use [postgresql_db](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/postgresql_db_module.html) module (maintained by the Ansible Core Team).

You can create, delete, or otherwise manipulate PostgreSQL databases in an idempotent way (you should always refrain from using `shell` and `cmd` modules whenever possible, since they are not idempotent by design).

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your ansible syntax but there is a flaw in shell command you're trying to execute.

`|` "pipe" connects the stdout of one command to the stdin of another, the way you're executing your command doesn't make any sense.

I would suggest creating a script and copying it over to achieve your goal.